# Android Studio: Can't start Git

Tags: android, git, android-studio

When I start Android Studio there's a message

> Can't start Git: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd Probably the
>   path to Git executable is not valid. Fix it.

But I can see that the git.cmd IS there. How do I fix the issue then?

Comment: In case you are getting the above error because you don't have Git installed on your machine, you can get it from https://git-scm.com/ and then set path in Android Studio to (for example) `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`.

Comment: Please refer [This thread will give some more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661484/os-x-cant-start-git-usr-bin-git-probably-the-path-to-git-executable-is-not)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd` is in you Path environment variable:

```
echo $env:Path
```

Comment: Correct. `git.exe` is under `\cmd` path.

Comment: Yes git.exe is in \cmd

Comment: I checked i dont have that folder :(

Comment: @aflatoon what about `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`?

Answer (score 108):

For some reason this morning, I had to agree to the terms and conditions by running git as administrator in the command line.

On the mac

`sudo /usr/bin/git`

On the pc

`c:\path\to\git.exe`

Accept the EULA.

After I did that, I was able to use git in my IDE.

Comment: Thanks @styler1972, that was exactly my problem also

Comment: This appears to be caused when Xcode has a major update. I had to go through this process when I upgraded to Yosemite. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Same here, had to do this after updating to Yosemite. Thanks!

Comment: After update to El Captain, maybe its necessary run this command line first: xcode-select --install (OSX)

Comment: It seems this came up when updating Mac OS X.

Comment: This one solves the problem `sudo /usr/bin/git`, but once I close Android Studio and open the project again, I have to round the command again. Does anyone know how to make it work even when I close Android Studio?

Comment: After this, I needed to restart android studio.

Answer (score 38):

For the one using mac who installed Xcode7, you have to **start Xcode and accept the license agreement** for the android studio error to go away.

Comment: This is the best ever...start Xcode to fix a problem in Android Studio...totally worked too!!  However it did ask me to quit iTunes first after opening Xcode, did that, then I went into AS and and clicked "Fix It"...the path was already in there, clicked test and it said Git executed successfully..not sure what wizardry this is that was the reason the ones and zeros fell into place like that....huh +1

Comment: This should be the correct answer. This was it for me.

Comment: 6 years later, Xcode 12.5 and Android Studio 4.2, and this is still relevant.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, this is how I fixed it:

I use windows...

Go to

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin
```

So in my Account I had this

```
C:\Users\victor\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin
```

Make sure you find the git.exe

Then go to the VCS window(`Settings --> Version Control---> Git`), and paste the PATH and append `git.exe` at  the end

So you shall have this

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin\git.exe
```

Then click test to verify if git is working well.

Comment: git.exe is in \cmd path

Comment: Obviously, this requires GitHub to be installed--which may not actually be the case

Answer (score 8):

In my case, with GitHub Desktop for Windows (as of June 2, 2016) & Android Studio 2.1:

This folder ->

```
C:\Users\(UserName)\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<hash>\
```

Contained a BATCH file called something like 'post-install.bat'.
Run this file to create a folder 'cmd' with 'git.exe' inside.

This path-->

```
C:\Users\(UserName)\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<hash>\cmd\git.exe
```

would be the location of 'git.exe' after running the post-install script.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  `C:\Users\(UserName)\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<hash>\cmd\git.exe` is path where i found my git.exe

Answer (score 8):

Try this...

1. Make sure, have you installed git on your machine. If not you can download(**Windows user**) from [here](https://gitforwindows.org/) and install it your system. For **Mac** user can download from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/)
2. Get location of **git.exe** 
   [image: Get location of git.exe]
3. Test git.exe manually
   [image: test]
4. Now you can set your **git.exe** location in android studio.

Answer (score 7):

Had to restart Android Studio after installing GIT for Windows.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `Mac OS` and have **updated `XCode`** you probably need to **open XCode and accept the terms** to avoid this error.

Answer (score 6):

Use bin folder and exe instead. Path will be C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe

Also sometimes it doesn't work if there are blank spaces in path name as in your program files directory name.

In that case, copy the whole git folder to root of partition and then link studio to it

Answer (score 6):

First make sure you have installed git scm or not. If not, here's the link for windows: https://git-for-windows.github.io/
Then go to Android studio and configure the link of Git to the place where you installed your git(probably in C:/program files)
I referred to a YouTube video to solve my issue. You can refer it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faEd2syXypE

Answer (score 4):

I showed my hide directories in windows 7 and find git.exe  in `C:\Users\(UserName)\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin\` and it works but I don't know why `git.exe` is there.
I installed `git version 1.9.5`

Comment: It looks like you have several git installed. Judging by the path name it is the one from [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/).

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio, goto File->Settings->Version Control->Git. Set the 'Path to Git Executable' to point to git.exe. Verify by clicking Test.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, my git was located at

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe`

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, I did a reinstall of xcode (This also presented user agreement).
I used the following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: This worked well for me as I'd previously uninstalled x-code & didn't need to re-install the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

The path for your git is invalid. Copy the path from File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git and search that folder and you can see the path to your Git is not valid. Reset the path with correct location and test it. The error should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo git --version` from command line and agree to the license and this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, you can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60279249/9005383).

But since links die too often, I'm going to leave a little part of the answer that might help:

> For people still having this error even if their `git` is installed
>   and android studio is pointing to its path, go to `Settings` ->
>   `Version Control` -> `Git` and delete everything inside the text box
>   with the label `Path to Git executable`, your android studio or what
>   ever JetBrains product you're using, will auto-detect it.