# How do I deal with missing git.exe error even after installing it?

Tags: git, flutter

I imported a flutter project from GitHub. I had missing git.exe error, then I installed Git from https://git-scm.com. I reopened the project even then I'm getting the same error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se1Bi.jpg)

Comment: Which Git version you have install? The latest (2.26.2)? And the flutter project from GitHub has no errors (missing git.exe)?

Comment: yeah! (2.26.2). What should I do after installing it in order to run the imported flutter project?

Comment: You have installed the two plugins for working with flutter?? You work with IntelliJ, right?

Comment: Nope. I use android studio

Comment: but the plugins you have? `Flutter` and `Dart`

Comment: I've installed both the plugins.

Comment: look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573340/git-exe-error-for-android-studio). Or what happens when you click `Download` in the error message...

Comment: when I clicked download  I got redirected to  https://git-scm.com, then I downloaded git latest version . I reopened the project after installing git. But even then I had the same message "File not found: git.exe".

Comment: and what about, when you don't install the latest version?

Comment: The same message